# How to transform code line to extjs4

Tags: extjs, ext.net

How to get the childnode in extjs 4 and Ext.net?

Ext.get(#{grdForms}.getView().getHeaderCell(0).childNodes[0])

Code to if All checkbox checked and then unselect a row,header check will be unchecked.

```
          function UncheckCheckHeader(control)
          {
            var grid=<%=grdForms.ClientID%>;
            var hd =Ext.get(grid.getView().getHeaderCell(0).childNodes[0]);       
            var store = grid.store;   
            if(store.getCount()== control.selections.items.length)
            {
              if(!hd.hasClass('x-grid3-hd-checker-on'))
              {
                hd.addClass('x-grid3-hd-checker-on');
              }
            }
            else
            {
              if(hd.hasClass('x-grid3-hd-checker-on'))
              {
                hd.removeClass('x-grid3-hd-checker-on');
              }
            }
          }
```

Comment: this line work fine with 1.X version of extjs.

Comment: Is this same as grid.getView().getHeaderCt(0).child(0)???

Comment: Now in v2, a column header is a real component, not just some DOM element. So, I think there is no a direct substitution for your code. I guess what you are doing, but, please, extend your question with a full v1 test case and I will help to migrate it v2.

Comment: Thanks Daniil, I try to edit that if needed more please Let me know. thanks in advance..

Comment: Thank you, it is better now. but, unfortunately, not enough. I expected a full sample which I can copy/paste and run. Could you provide?

Comment: Thanks but its not easy to share complete ...try to suggest me something.

Comment: Ok, please clarify what you are actually doing. The requirement. Do you use a CheckboxSelectionModel? It seems to provide by default the functionality you need.

Comment: Yes I have CheckBoxSelectionModel and Ext.get(grid.getView().getHeaderCell(0).childNodes[0]) is used to select and deselect all.

Comment: I have a HeaderClick Event as well on which check the 'x-grid3-hd-checker-on' if it exist the selectAll Otherwise Deselect.

Comment: There is a header checkbox in this example, which, seems, provides the functionality you need, doesn't? http://examples1.ext.net/#/GridPanel/Selection_Models/Checkbox_Selection/

Comment: Yes I already seen this but its quite different.

Comment: Are you using HeaderItems? I ask because I do not understand, what exactly you are having and doing. A full sample would be appreciated. At least, the GridPanel's configuration including the episode where the UncheckCheckHeader function is called.

Comment: Thanks I try to create a demo.